# Why not cudaMemcpyAsync(host to device) and CUDA kernel are parallel?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I have loaded an image (8 bit, unsigned char) of size `1080 x 1920`. For the testing purposes, I am processing the same image 4 times using a `for loop` and then, generating its timeline profiling.

**Strategy:** I am dividing the image into 3 parts. I have made three streams for the processing of this whole image.

I am providing a minimal working example below. I am sorry that it will need an image using OpenCV but I don't know how can I mimic the same situation without loading an image using OpenCV.

**Problem:** The timeline profiling shows that the first stream has finished transferring the data but still the kernel assigned to it did not start. The kernel assigned to the first stream and the data transfer by third stream are parallel. ***So, my question is that why the processing of first stream's kernel did not start in parallel with the data transfer of second stream?***

**GPU:** NVIDIA Quadro K2000, Compatible 3.0

**Timeline profile:** Each stream has been assigned a different color.

[image]

**My code:**

```
__global__ void multiStream_ColorTransformation_kernel(int numChannels, int iw, int ih, unsigned char *ptr_source, unsigned char *ptr_dst)
{
    // Calculate our pixel's location
    int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

    // Operate only if we are in the correct boundaries
    if (x >= 0 && x < iw && y >= 0 && y < ih / 3)
    {
        ptr_dst[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 0] = ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 0];
        ptr_dst[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 1] = ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 1];
        ptr_dst[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 2] = ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 2];

    }
}

void callMultiStreamingCudaKernel(unsigned char *dev_src, unsigned char *dev_dst, int numChannels, int iw, int ih, cudaStream_t *ptr_stream)
{

    dim3 numOfBlocks((iw / 20), (ih / 20)); //DON'T multiply by 3 because we have 1/3 data of image
    dim3 numOfThreadsPerBlocks(20, 20);
    multiStream_ColorTransformation_kernel << <numOfBlocks, numOfThreadsPerBlocks, 0, *ptr_stream >> >(numChannels, iw, ih, dev_src, dev_dst);

    return;
}

int main()
{

    cudaStream_t stream_one;
    cudaStream_t stream_two;
    cudaStream_t stream_three;

    cudaStreamCreate(&stream_one);
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream_two);
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream_three);

    Mat image = imread("DijSDK_test_image.jpg", 1);
    //Mat image(1080, 1920, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,255));
    size_t numBytes = image.rows * image.cols * 3;
    int numChannels = 3;

    int iw = image.rows;
    int ih = image.cols;
    size_t totalMemSize = numBytes * sizeof(unsigned char);
    size_t oneThirdMemSize = totalMemSize / 3;

    unsigned char *dev_src_1, *dev_src_2, *dev_src_3, *dev_dst_1, *dev_dst_2, *dev_dst_3, *h_src, *h_dst;


    //Allocate memomry at device for SOURCE and DESTINATION and get their pointers
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_src_1, (totalMemSize) / 3);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_src_2, (totalMemSize) / 3);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_src_3, (totalMemSize) / 3);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dst_1, (totalMemSize) / 3);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dst_2, (totalMemSize) / 3);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dst_3, (totalMemSize) / 3);

    //Get the processed image 
    Mat org_dijSDK_img(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
    h_dst = org_dijSDK_img.data;

    //while (1)
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\nLoop: " << i;

        //copy new data of image to the host pointer
        h_src = image.data;

        //Copy the source image to the device i.e. GPU
        cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_src_1, h_src, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream_one);
        //KERNEL--stream-1
        callMultiStreamingCudaKernel(dev_src_1, dev_dst_1, numChannels, iw, ih, &stream_one);


        //Copy the source image to the device i.e. GPU
        cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_src_2, h_src + oneThirdMemSize, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream_two);
        //KERNEL--stream-2
        callMultiStreamingCudaKernel(dev_src_2, dev_dst_2, numChannels, iw, ih, &stream_two);

        //Copy the source image to the device i.e. GPU
        cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_src_3, h_src + (2 * oneThirdMemSize), (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream_three);
        //KERNEL--stream-3
        callMultiStreamingCudaKernel(dev_src_3, dev_dst_3, numChannels, iw, ih, &stream_three);


        //RESULT copy: GPU to CPU
        cudaMemcpyAsync(h_dst, dev_dst_1, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream_one);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(h_dst + oneThirdMemSize, dev_dst_2, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream_two);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(h_dst + (2 * oneThirdMemSize), dev_dst_3, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream_three);

        // wait for results 
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_one);
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_two);
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_three);

        //Assign the processed data to the display image.
        org_dijSDK_img.data = h_dst;
        //DISPLAY PROCESSED IMAGE           
        imshow("Processed dijSDK image", org_dijSDK_img);
        waitKey(33);
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE-1:** If I remove the kernel call of first stream then, the second kernel and H2D copy of third stream are somehow overlapped (not completely) as shown below.

[image: image2]

**UPDATE-2** I even tried to use 10 streams and the things remain same. The first stream's kernel processing began only after the H2D copy of tenth's stream data.

[image: image-3]

Comment: But you have copy/execution overlap occurring in every stream in that profile data you are showing

Comment: overlap is occurring for the execution of first stream's kernel and third streams H2D copy. My question is, why the execution of first stream's kernel did not start immediately after the H2D copy of first stream's data.

Comment: @talonmies: there is no overlap between the execution of first stream's kernel and H2D data copy of second stream. That is my question. Rest of the parts are fine.

Comment: if you remove the first stream, does the second one start processing immediately after copying data 2 or will it wait till after data 3?

Comment: @Micka: Please have a look at my updates. I have updated the question for that case.

Comment: Try performing the three cudaMemcpyAsync H2D lines sequentially, then spawn the compute kernels. http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-overlap-data-transfers-cuda-cc/

Comment: I guess further removal of cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_src_1,... in thr reduced sample doesnt change the result further?

Comment: @putnampp: I have tried that but the results are exactly same as posted in question.

Comment: @Micka: Sorry, I did not get your meaning.

Comment: @Micka: if we carefully observe then we can see a pattern. The kernel processing begins only when the last call of mem copy is about to finish. I am new but I think that it is related to some sort of constraint to the access of GPU memory or something like that (just a rough guess).

Comment: Is the host memory pinned? [The documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution) states that the host memory must be paged locked for overlap to happen.

Comment: @Jez: I just realized that. I will post the results in a couple of minutes

Comment: might this be a problem of architecture? did you study http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-overlap-data-transfers-cuda-cc/ ? It mentions the need of the memory to be `pinned`, and in addition the compute capability, but yours is 3.0 so high enough...

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd also advise reading through section 3.2.5 of the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ixzz3g3oTRk2Q), which discusses concurrent execution and all of the weird quirks that can be involved with it. In particular, there are some extra restrictions that apply to devices of CC less than _or equal to_ 3.0.

Comment: @ALL: thanks, pinned memory solved the problem.

Comment: opencv has its own ways to copy Mat data to GPU, see gpu::CudaMem. If you dont want to use those maybe you have to deep-copy the data or use your pinned memory as input pointer of a cv::Mat or sth. might be completely wrong though, didnt use openCV in combination with Cuda yet.

Comment: Actually, my actual image will not be an OpenCV image in my actualy Project. I will get the image data in `unsigned char` form and then I need to do these things on it. I have solved the problem by allocating pinned memory at host and then copying my image data to this pinned memory using memcpy(). I am afraid that memcpy() will be an efficient way or not. Any suggestion?

Comment: where does your original unsigned char data come from? aren't you allowed to provide some memory area where it will be "generated" in first place? normally camera APIs etc will provide such a feature.

Comment: @Micka: In the project, the image flow from one processing part to another in `unsigned char` form. This CUDA processing part lie somewhere inbetween so, I do not have the access to the raw image. But please let me know your suggestion and I will try to modify the image pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters already pointed out, host memory must be [page locked](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution).

There is no need to allocate additional host memory through `cudaHostAlloc`, you can use [`cudaHostRegister`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g36b9fe28f547f28d23742e8c7cd18141.html) on your existing OpenCV image:

```
cudaHostRegister(image.data, totalMemSize, cudaHostRegisterPortable)
```

Comment: Actually, my actual image will not be an OpenCV image. I will get the image data in `unsigned char` form and then I need to do these things on it. I have solved the problem by allocating pinned memory at host and then copying my image data to this pinned memory using `memcpy()`. I am afraid that `memcpy()` will be an efficient way or not.

Comment: @skm you can still use `cudaHostRegister`, it does not depend on a OpenCV image. just pass your `unsigned char*` pointer as the first argument

Comment: Can you tell me, is it also possible to overlap the kernel execution? I tried to use 20 streams to reduce the kernel size but still kernel processing did not overlapped.

Comment: @skm it depends both on your GPU and the kernel launch configuration: ["Threadblocks for a given kernel are scheduled if all threadblocks for preceding kernels have been 
scheduled and there still are SM resources available"](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf) and also read [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/743419/max-1-or-2-concurrent-kernels-per-sm-/)